# how to bring ProgressBar in center of the screen and remove warning message in react native

Tags: android, react-native, progress-bar, warnings

how to bring the progress bar to the center of the screen like we do in android center in parent in relative layout and how to remove the warning message.How to change the visibility(invisible or gone or visible) in progressbar.
[MyScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKJeE.png)

```
var ProgressBar = require('ProgressBarAndroid');
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'steelblue', padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{
            backgroundColor: 'steelblue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 40, textAlign: 'center',
            color: 'white', marginBottom: 30
        }}>LOGIN</Text>
        <ProgressBar style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',styleAttr:'LargeInverse', color:'white'}} />
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <TextInput
                style={{ height: 50, marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30, marginBottom: 20, color: 'white', fontSize: 20 }}
                placeholder='Username' placeholderTextColor='white'
                autoFocus={true}
                returnKeyType='next'
                keyboardType='email-address'
                onChangeText={(valUsername) => _values.username = valUsername}
                />
            <TextInput
                secureTextEntry={true}
                style={{ height: 50, marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30, marginBottom: 20, color: 'white', fontSize: 20 }}
                placeholder='Password' placeholderTextColor='white'
                onChangeText={(valPassword) => _values.password = valPassword}
                />
        </View>
        <Button onPress={() => { _handlePress() } } label='Login' />
        <View>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 20, textDecorationLine: 'underline', textDecorationStyle: 'solid' }}>
                Forgot Password
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', marginTop: 10, justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 20, textDecorationLine: 'underline', textDecorationStyle: 'solid' }}>
                SignUp
            </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: try using ActivityIndicator instead of progressbar.Also what do you mean by center of screen? As an overlay ?

Comment: yes like a overlay in center and how to change its visibility

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30870639/4321808

Comment: no my progressbar is not getting in center of the screen

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @ravi-teja, use absolute positioning. Also, your warning arises because `styleAttr` is not a style attribute (the name is misleading) but a prop. You can also show and hide it programmatically using a boolean (`myCondition`) (that you can maybe store in your state). You should do something like this:

```
var ProgressBar = require('ProgressBarAndroid');

// ...
render(){
    const {width, heigth} = Dimensions.get('window'); // The dimensions may change due to the device being rotated, so you need to get them in each render.
    return (

       //...
       {this.state.myCondition && <ProgressBar styleAttr={'LargeInverse'} style={{position: 'absolute', left: width/2, height: height/2, justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', color:'white'}} />}
       //...
}
```

In addition to that and as others said, you should give a try to `ActivityIndicator`, since it works for both iOS and Android.

Comment: initial state of mycondition=false, when i change the mycondition=true, i am not able to see the ActivityIndicator(progressbar) on my screen how to refresh to show the indicator. I tried your way by setting absolute and other still my activityindicator is shown at end of the screen left side. Above i have posted my screen and my view code.

Comment: Are you using `this.setState({myCondition: true})` to update the value? Otherwise it will not trigger a render. Try without the `justifyContent` and `alignItems` styles.

Comment: i am not using state i am using const _showProgress = {
    progress: false
} is there any other way to refresh without using state

Comment: There are some ways (by using a flux-based pattern, for instance), but the simplest case is using the state. The idea of react is that a component is always is sync with its props and its state, so the only way of triggering a render is to update one of those.

Comment: https://github.com/yuvaraj119/ReactNative/blob/master/NavigationSample/app/components/Login.js
this is my sample project Login Screen how to add props or state in this because this is not a class.Please can you look at it how to add state