overlay on top of image in react native

i want that blue only on top of the image and nowhere else. i am not able to get it to work.Is there any way to do that.have tried many things and none of them work
<View
        style={{
          flex:5,
          position:"relative",
          width:450,
          height:450,
        }}
        >
           <Image
           source={{
            uri: Image.resolveAssetSource(require('../assets/asset1.png')).uri
           }}
           style={{
               width: 450,
               height: 450,
               backgroundColor:"transparent",
               zIndex: 1
           }}
           >
           </Image>
           <View
            style={{
               width: 450,
               height: 150,
               backgroundColor: 'blue',
               position: 'absolute',
               left: 0,
               bottom: 240,
               right: 0,
               justifyContent: 'center',
               alignItems: 'center',
               zIndex: 0,
            }}
            >
            </View>
        </View>


If you want on the top why are you using bottom: 240?

Try changing the position of the view and the image. Try to add view first and then image ? Maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638739/transparent-overlay-in-react-native
Instead of relative maybe try absolute position as well
